# TarWriter throws Gem::Package::TarWriter::FileOverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tar

I want to generate a tar from a buch of files.

```
out_file = File.new('some.tar', 'w')
tar = Gem::Package::TarWriter.new out_file
attachments = #Array of attachment objects
attachments.each{|a|
   file = Attachment.new(a).read_file #returns a String
   file.force_encoding('UTF-8')
   tar.add_file_simple( a[:filename], 777, file.length) do |io|
      io.write(file)
    end
}
```

> Gem::Package::TarWriter::FileOverflow - You tried to feed more data
>   than fits in the file.

Has anyone an idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String#length` returns the number of characters in the String. Since a UTF-8 character can be represented by more than a single byte, the bytesize of a string is usually larger.

The `TarWriter` now expects the file size to be given in bytes. Thus, if you use anything else than plain ascii characters in your file, it will overflow.

To solve this, you should thus pass [`file.bytesize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-bytesize) to the `add_file_simple` method instead of `file.size`.